# Rails compress assets even in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets

Rails just compress javascript in development mode but i dont need to.
Here is the config/environments/development.rb

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

Rails version is 3.2.8 but also tried 3.2.9-rc3, 3.1.8 doesnt work with my application because it was created in 3.2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found that rails serves precompiled assets instead of assets from app/ catalog when they are exist. Its need to remove them to make Rails work like i need.

```
rake assets:clean
```

I belive Rails must not behave that way in development mode.

Comment: I tried this on my local machine and got the following message:

$ rake assets:clean
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake assets:clean:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rm -rf /Users/user/Sites/rnrmatchbook/public/assets

The "RAILS_ENV=production" puzzles me.
Shouldn't this be the development environment?
Have I somehow set it to be production?